# How to remove the RichText Meta Box

Tags: metabox, filters

How can I remove the rich text box editor in WordPress? I have used the `remove_meta_box` function specifying the boxes ID, but it does not work like it does for other core meta boxes:

The code I tried:

```
function remove_rich_box()
{
    remove_meta_box('postdivrich', 'client', 'normal');  
}
add_action( 'do_meta_boxes', 'remove_rich_box' );
```

Where the second paratmeter "client" is my custom post type.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to remove it like a metabox, since it isn't one.

However, there's a very easy way to get rid of it for a custom post type. If you don't define anything for the `'supports'` argument in the registration function, your post type will default to

```
'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor' ),
```

To stop that, add this to your registration arguments array:

```
'supports' => array( 'title' ),
```